# Oddly formatted SVN repo to Git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm working to port an extremely old svn repo that, unfortunately, was made in a non-standard way. Check out the format below:

```
PROJECT/
  trunk/
    service1/
    service2/
  branches/
    service1-1.0
    service1-1.1
    service1.1.2
    service2-1.0
  tags/
    service1-1.0.0
    service1-1.0.1
    service2.1.0.0
```

Now the git repo only needs to be converted once -- we don't need to support both at the same time. I've attempted a few different ways to do this. The closest I've gotten is something like this:

`svn2git --username user.name --trunk trunk/service1 --branches branches/service1-* --tags tags/service1-* --revision 12 --authors ../authors.txt -v https://www.domain.com/svn/PROJECT/`

I'd be really grateful if anyone could lend a hand! Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks Alexis. Forgot to post that bit. Here is the output:
`Invalid pattern in 'PROJECT/branches/service1-*': service1-*`

Comment: What is the problem with what you tried, and how does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the root of the branches and tags at the branches and tags folder level. Then remove the branches and tags you don't need for each project afterwards.